# adding column to select gives group_by error

Tags: sql, h2

I have a following query:

```
SELECT transactions.created,
       installments.*,
       transactions.installment_id,
       Sum(transactions.amount) AS s,
       Sum(installments.amount) AS s1
FROM   installments
       LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions
                    ON transactions.installment_id = installments.id
WHERE  installments.customer_id = ?
GROUP  BY installments.id
```

which gives me error

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "TRANSACTIONS.CREATED" must be in
>   the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:

But I need the created field and don't want to use it in GROUP_BY.

Comment: try using `min(transactions.created)` or `max(...)`

Comment: @DanGetz after using it how can I show the created date of each transaction?

Comment: adding min(transactions.created) solved my problem. But should I optimize the query further?

Comment: Not sure what output you want exactly, so it is not clear how to optimize. But if the query works, it should be OK. No need to optimize too much - it can lead to trouble sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,s,S1,created
FROM installments
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) AS s, SUM(installments.amount) AS  
  s1,created
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY created
) A ON A.installment_id = installments.id 
WHERE installments.customer_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Including it in the `GROUP BY` fixes the syntax problem:

```
SELECT t.created, i.*,
       Sum(t.amount) AS s,
       Sum(i.amount) AS s1
FROM installments i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     transactions t
     ON t.installment_id = i.id
WHERE i.customer_id = ?
GROUP BY i.id, t.created;
```

But the real issue is that you might have multiple transactions.  Which `created` value do you want?  You probably intend something more like:

```
SELECT Min(t.created) as created, i.*,
       Sum(t.amount) AS s,
       Sum(i.amount) AS s1
FROM installments i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     transactions t
     ON t.installment_id = i.id
WHERE i.customer_id = ?
GROUP BY i.id;
```

I should note that the calculation of s1 is probably wrong, because it is getting multiplied by the number of transactions.  I'm thinking something more like this may be what you intend:

```
SELECT t.created, i.*,
       t.amount as s,
       Sum(i.amount) as s1
FROM installments i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT t.installment_id, t.created as created,
             SUM(t.amount) as s
      FROM transactions t
      GROUP BY t.installment_id
     ) t
     ON t.installment_id = i.id
WHERE i.customer_id = ?
GROUP BY i.id, t.created, t.amount;
```

Comment: actually i need only first created of each group of transactions

Comment: That would be `MIN()` instead of `MAX()`.

Comment: If you * in select statment,You must specify all columns in group by

Comment: @Mansoor . . . The `i.*` is actually fine in this place -- assuming that `i.id` is unique in the table.  This usage is even supported by ANSI.  It goes by the name "functional dependency".  I should note:  This is a special case.